# Cannot instantiate the type Pair although not abstract

Tags: java, generics, instantiation

Trying to write an iterator that returns a Pair:
Part of my PairIterator

```
public Pair next() {
            this.counter ++;
            Pair p = new Pair(this.l.get(counter - 1), this.l.get(counter)); 
            //error occurs here

        }

public class Pair<E> {
    private E e1;
    private E e2;

    public Pair(E e1, E e2) {
        this.e1 = e1;
        this.e2 = e2;
    }
    public E first() {
        return this.e1;
    }
    public E second() {
        return this.e2;
    }
}
```

getting

> Cannot instantiate the type Pair

... although Pair is not an abstract class/interface. Why is this happening?

Comment: What is this.counter? No mention any where!

Comment: I see no examples of 'new Pair' here, so we cannot guess what you did.

Comment: counter is probably a long or an ind, but what type is this.l?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). 
Please 
provide 
a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](/help/mcve)

Comment: @bmargulies "new Pair" appears in the 3rd line of the snippet.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to import the correct class to initialize your pair object.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.Pair;
```

Concrete Class -> Can directly create object.

This gives an error:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
```

Its an abstract class, so you can't create the object directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair` (or `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.MutablePair`) instead; those classes are concrete so they can be instantiated.

Answer (score -4):

Most likely because you didn't add generic type parameters to Pair.